# Rigid body bounces away when starting animation

Tags: animation, rigidbody

I'm trying to create an animation in which a ball is placed on a plane which I'll then animate by rotating it in different directions. However, as soon as I check the "Animation" box under Rigid body settings for the plane, the ball bounces away rather than fall down on the plane.

I've attached a gif below which hopefully is helpful.

Here is a link to the blender file as well: https://pasteall.org/blend/660da9a9fcac418eb1c1d67263c1425e

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be incredibly helpful.

[image: example]

Comment: please provide blend file, because there are many reasons, why this can happen https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi Chris, 

Of course! Here's the blender file: https://pasteall.org/blend/660da9a9fcac418eb1c1d67263c1425e

Thanks!

Comment: moonboots was quicker than i was and he is right - because he is THE MASTER ;)

Comment: i think you missed the 'S' for Superman.... :D

Comment: aha I'm the Beastmaster  ;)  https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6c/5e/13/6c5e13d48816a4670f415c9393263f80.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Apply the scale of your cube (maybe you could also disable the *Animated* option and switch it to *Passive*, it depends on what you want to do with it)

Result after applying the scale with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> Scale:

[image]

Comment: wow, Great animated result added moonboots, you know i love your great answers! :D

Comment: no problem for the edit but I don't have the same result as you if I apply the scale, the ball simply fall on the cube, I'm not sure why it jumps up in your case?

Comment: really? i thought i just applied the scale....